# Extjs Spreadsheet Model - Locking row number column

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs 6 version and I have a spreadsheet model buffered grid. I want to lock the rownumber column when user scrolls horizontally he can see the row number if the column is fixed. I am able to lock the other columns but not the rownumber.

I would appreciate for your help.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Actually the grid is dynamically created based on the column configuration from the API , so we are doing lot of customization . The code is too big to attach here .. but I can share the code where am overriding one of the method of spreadsheet model to change the RowNumber column properties such as Text,Color etc . 

Code added in the next comment

Comment: getNumbererColumnConfig: function() {
    var me = this;
    return {
        xtype: 'rownumberer',

        /* Custom Paging changes - Start */
        text: 'Line#',
        align: 'center',
        //locked:true,
        ignoreExport: false,
        /* Custom Paging changes - End */

        width: me.rowNumbererHeaderWidth,
        editRenderer: '&#160;',
        tdCls: me.rowNumbererTdCls,
        cls: me.rowNumbererHeaderCls,
        locked: true
    };
},

Answer (score 0):

I think somehow you have to manage `hasLockedHeader` to true

```
getNumbererColumnConfig: function() {
    var me = this;

    return {
      xtype: 'rownumberer',
      width: me.rowNumbererHeaderWidth,
      editRenderer:  '&#160;',
      tdCls: me.rowNumbererTdCls,
      cls: me.rowNumbererHeaderCls,
      locked: me.hasLockedHeader
    };
},
```

**OR**
 you can do this

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
 renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
 store: userStore,
 storeId: 'mystore',
 width: 200,
 title: 'Application Users',
 selModel: {
    type: 'spreadsheet'
 },
 columns: [{
    xtype: 'rownumberer',
    locked:true
 }, {
    text: 'Name',
    width: 100,
    sortable: false,
    hideable: false,
    dataIndex: 'name'
 }, {
    text: 'Email Address',
    width: 150,
    dataIndex: 'email',
 }, {
    text: 'Phone Number',
    flex: 1,
    dataIndex: 'phone'
 }]
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2j44

Comment: Thank you Snehal . I will try like this.